# Copy part of the content of the previous row into the following

Tags: text-processing, cygwin

I have a file with the following structure:

```
GO:0000001      mitochondrion inheritance
GO:0000002      mitochondrial genome maintenance
GO:0000003      reproduction
alt_id: GO:0019952
alt_id: GO:0050876
GO:0000005      obsolete ribosomal chaperone activity
GO:0000006      high-affinity zinc uptake transmembrane transporter activity
GO:0000007      low-affinity zinc ion transmembrane transporter activity
GO:0000008      obsolete thioredoxin
alt_id: GO:0000013
GO:0000009      alpha-1,6-mannosyltransferase activity
```

Where it says `alt_id` it means that it is an alternative to the previous `GO:` code.
I'd like to add to each `alt_id` the definition of the previous `GO:`, that is, I want an output like this:

```
GO:0000001      mitochondrion inheritance
GO:0000002      mitochondrial genome maintenance
GO:0000003      reproduction
alt_id: GO:0019952     reproduction
alt_id: GO:0050876     reproduction
GO:0000005      obsolete ribosomal chaperone activity
GO:0000006      high-affinity zinc uptake transmembrane transporter activity
GO:0000007      low-affinity zinc ion transmembrane transporter activity
GO:0000008      obsolete thioredoxin
alt_id: GO:0000013      obsolete thioredoxin
GO:0000009      alpha-1,6-mannosyltransferase activity
```

How can I copy the content of the previous row in the following? I work with Cygwin in a Windows-based environment.

Comment: What is the separator between `GO:0000001` and `mitochondrion inheritance`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`, not sure if it will work on `Cygwin`

```
$ awk '{ if(/^alt_id/){$0 = $0" "p} else{p = ""; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) p = p" "$i} } 1' ip.txt
GO:0000001      mitochondrion inheritance
GO:0000002      mitochondrial genome maintenance
GO:0000003      reproduction
alt_id: GO:0019952  reproduction
alt_id: GO:0050876  reproduction
GO:0000005      obsolete ribosomal chaperone activity
GO:0000006      high-affinity zinc uptake transmembrane transporter activity
GO:0000007      low-affinity zinc ion transmembrane transporter activity
GO:0000008      obsolete thioredoxin
alt_id: GO:0000013  obsolete thioredoxin
GO:0000009      alpha-1,6-mannosyltransferase activity
```

- For every line not matching `alt_id` at start of line, use a variable (`p`) to save all columns from two onwards
- When line matches `alt_id` at start of line, append the contents of `p` variable to input line contained in `$0` variable
- The final `1` is short cut to print the contents of `$0`

Answer (score 1):

The task can be easy done by **sed**

```
sed '
    N  #append next line (operate with `line1\nline2`);
    /\nalt_id/s/\([^0-9]*\)\n.*/&\1/
       #if next line starts with `alt_id` the append end of present line
    P  #print present line (all before `\n`)
    D  #remove all before `\n`, starts from begin with remain part (line2)
    ' file
```

Other way is use hold-space

```
sed '
    /^alt_id:/G #if line starts by `alt_id:` append hold-space
    s/\n//      #remove `\n`ewline symbol
    t           #if removing success pass further commands (go to end)
    h           #if no (for other lines) copy it to hold-space
    s/\S*//     #remove all non-space symbols from start till first space
    x           #exchange hold-space and pattern-space ==
                #+put resedue into hold-space and return full line
    ' file
```